# Chain homotopy equivalence after tensoring

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, tensor-products, homotopy-theory, free-modules

Let $M$ be a commutative ring with a subring $R \subset M$ and let $(C_\bullet,\partial^C)$, $(D_\bullet,\partial^D)$ be two chain complexes that are freely and finitely generated $R$-modules in every degree with the boundary operators being $R$-linear.

Let us assume that $C_\bullet$ and $D_\bullet$ are chain homotopy equivalent over $R$, i.e. there exist two chain maps
$$i \colon C_\bullet \to D_\bullet, \, j \colon D_\bullet \to C_\bullet$$ that are $R$-linear so that both $j \circ i$ and $i \circ j$ are chain homotopic (over $R$) to the respective identities $\mathrm{id}_{C}$ and $\mathrm{id}_D$.

After tensoring with $M$ over $R$ we obtain two new chain complexes $(C_\bullet \otimes_R M,\partial^C \otimes \mathrm{id}_M)$ and $(D_\bullet \otimes_R M,\partial^D \otimes \mathrm{id}_M)$. Note that these two are now also $M$-modules with the action given by
$n \cdot (c \otimes m):=c \otimes n \cdot m$ for $c \in C_\bullet, \, m,n \in M$ (similarly for $D_\bullet \otimes_R M$).

I did a direct computation and believe to have shown that $$I:=i \otimes \mathrm{id}_M \text{ and } J:=j\otimes \mathrm{id}_M$$ define a $M$-linear chain homotopy equivalence.

**Question:** Is this true or have I gone wrong somewhere? If it's true, does one have a reference to such a result? It looks so standard and easy, but I couldn't find any similar statement which led to some serious doubts...

Comment: Yes this is true, and more generally, in any abelian category, if $f,g:C_\bullet\to D_\bullet$ are two homotopic chain maps, then for any additive functor $F$, the maps $F(f), F(g):F(C_\bullet)\to F(D_\bullet)$ are still homotopic. It follows that any additive functor preserve homotopy equivalence as well. No assumption is needed, in particular you don't need to assume that the complexes are free.

Comment: I agree about the freeness not being releveant. Is $F \colon \mathsf{mod}_R \to \mathsf{mod}_M$, $F(C):=C\otimes_R M$, $F(i):=i\otimes \mathrm{id}$ an additive functor? Sorry, haven't seen this notion before. Do you happen to have a reference at hands? Thanks!

Comment: Yes this functor is additive. I don't have a reference but it should be in any book on homological algebra. Or prove it, it is really straightforward from the definitions.

Comment: Great thank, I'll have a look then.